# When installing an application is there any way to avoid any drag and drop?

Tags: macos, install, dmg

When installing an application from a DMG file one needs to drag the new application into the application folder ([or some other folders](https://superuser.com/q/157765/116475)).

Is there any way to avoid this drag and drop (any new installed application would be automatically placed into the application folder)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do You want to achieve this? Dragging (or copying) this app IS installing. `dmg` can be unmounted and is read only and that's why You have to move the application to Your local HDD.

Comment: Is there a reason for wanting this e.g. automatic installation - there might be solutions to that problem

Comment: @Mark I want to minimize the number of mouse actions and key strokes that needs to be done to install a program.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Automatically detecting the presence of a program in a DMG and copying it to the application folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could copy/paste it. Might be simpler if you can't see the Apps folder right at that moment.

It will stay in the paste buffer so long as the .dmg is still mounted, unless overwritten by another copy action.

Frankly, it would be far more effort than it's worth to try automate that process, for any given .dmg with random content.

Comment: Thanks, good to know there is this alternative. Ideally I'd like to only have to click on the DMG though.